# XSLT: Return Next Node Based on Current

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I feel like I'm missing something simple and/or overthinking it.  The answers I've found here and elsewhere on the web have gotten me close, but something is different that keeps tripping me up.  I'm stuck with XSL 1.0.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Items>
<Data>
<Class>
  <List>
    <Elements>
      <Property>1</Property>
      <Property>Date</Property>
      <Property>08/10/10</Property>
    </Elements>
    <Elements>
      <Property>2</Property>
      <Property>Time</Property>
      <Property>21:09:11</Property>
    </Elements>
    <Elements>
      <Property>3</Property>
      <Property>User</Property>
      <Property>Mario</Property>
    </Elements>
  </List>
</Class>
<Class>
  <List>
    <Elements>
      <Property>1</Property>
      <Property>Date</Property>
      <Property>10/12/14</Property>
    </Elements>
    <Elements>
      <Property>2</Property>
      <Property>Time</Property>
      <Property>08:10:00</Property>
    </Elements>
    <Elements>
      <Property>3</Property>
      <Property>User</Property>
      <Property>Luigi</Property>
    </Elements>
  </List>
</Class>
</Data>
</Items>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' indent='no' method='xml' />
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Data/Class">
        <TR>
            <xsl:for-each select="List/Elements">
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="Property['Date']/following-sibling::Property[1]" /></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="Property['Time']/following-sibling::Property[1]" /></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="Property['User']/following-sibling::Property[1]" /></TD>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TR>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<TR>
  <TD>08/10/10</TD>
  <TD>21:09:11</TD>
  <TD>Mario</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD>10/12/14</TD>
  <TD>08:10:00</TD>
  <TD>Luigi</TD>
</TR>
```

Basically, go through the Property's ... if it's Date, then return the next one ... if it's Time, then return the next one ... and if it's User, then return the next one.  Continue through all Class's.

My select isn't quite right, and I can't get past the first Element.  Do I need another for-each or choose/when statements?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Data/Class">
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="List/Elements[Property='Date']/Property[3]" />
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="List/Elements[Property='Time']/Property[3]" />
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="List/Elements[Property='User']/Property[3]" />
            </TD>
        </TR>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Or perhaps just:

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Data/Class">
        <TR>
            <xsl:for-each select="List/Elements">
                <TD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Property[3]" />
                </TD>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TR>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that the result is not a well-formed XML document (no single root element).

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Your first solution works.  I neglected to specify in my example, but there are indeed other Elements that I do not want to include so the matching is important for these criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a push-type (template matching instead of a pull type [for-each]) method. Explanations are included:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml' />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- set Class tags -->
    <xsl:template match="Class">
        <TR>
            <!-- apply Elements node -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="List/Elements"/>
        </TR>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Elements">
        <TD>
            <!-- get the target node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="Property[3]"/>
        </TD>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- set table headers -->
    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <TABLE>
            <TR>
                <TD>Date</TD>
                <TD>Time</TD>
                <TD>User</TD>
            </TR>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- delete unwanted tags -->
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```